# mock rest template for unit test

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I want to mock a `RestTemplate` in Spring Boot, where I'm making a REST call within a method. To test the controller of the microservice I'm creating,
I want to test methods inside the controller of my micro service.

For example:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getMasterDataView", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
@CrossOrigin(origins = { "http://192.1**********" }, maxAge = 3000)
public ResponseEntity<MasterDataViewDTO> getMasterDataView() throws IOException {

    final String uri = "http://localhost:8089/*********";

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    MasterDataViewDTO masterDataViewDTO = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, MasterDataViewDTO.class);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(masterDataViewDTO, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

how to I test this using mocking?

This is what I have so far:

```
@Test
    public void testgetMasterDataView() throws IOException {

    MasterDataViewDTO masterDataViewDTO= mock(MasterDataViewDTO.class);
    //String uri = "http://localhost:8089/*********"; 

    Mockito.when(restTemplate.getForObject(Mockito.anyString(),ArgumentMatchers.any(Class.class))).thenReturn(masterDataViewDTO);

    assertEquals("OK",inquiryController.getMasterDataView().getStatusCode());        
}
```

I am getting an error when I'm running the mock, the method `getMasterDataView()` is getting called and the REST call within it is also getting called and is throwing an error. How can I write my test so that the REST endpoint is not called? If it's possible, I'd like to do this with Mockito.

Comment: is there a possibility of doing this using mockito. as we are advised to test using mockito in our project

Answer (score 3):

Before you start writing a test, you should change your code a bit. First of all, it would be a lot easier if you extracted that `RestTemplate`, and created a separate bean for it which you would inject within your controller.

To do that, add something like this within a `@Configuration` class or within your main class:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

Additionally, you have to remove the `new RestTemplate()` from your controller, and autowire it in stead, for example:

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

Now that you've done that, it's going to be a lot easier to inject a mock `RestTemplate` within your tests.

For your testing, you have two options:

1. Either mock `RestTemplate` and all the methods you are trying to access, using a mocking framework (eg. Mockito)
2. Or you can use `MockRestServiceServer`, which allows you to write tests that verify if the URLs are properly called, the request matches, and so on.

## Testing with Mockito

To mock your `RestTemplate` with Mockito, you have to make sure that you add the following annotation to your tests:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

After that, you can do this:

```
@InjectMocks
private MyController controller;
@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

And now you can adjust your tests like this:

```
@Test
public void testgetMasterDataView() throws IOException {
    MasterDataViewDTO dto = new MasterDataViewDTO();
    when(restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8089/*********", MasterDataViewDTO.class)).thenReturn(dto);
    ResponseEntity<MasterDataViewDTO> response = controller.getMasterDataView();
    assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
    assertThat(response.getBody()).isEqualTo(dto);
}
```

You could mock the DTO as you did within your test, but you don't have to, and I don't think there's any benefit from doing so. What you do have to mock is the `restTemplate.getForObject(..)` call.

## Testing with `MockRestServiceServer`

Another approach is to use `MockRestServiceServer`. To do that, you have to use the following annotations for your test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RestClientTest
```

And then you'll have to autowire your controller and `MockRestServiceServer`, for example:

```
@Autowired
private MyController controller;
@Autowired
private MockRestServiceServer server;
```

And now you can write tests like this:

```
@Test
public void testgetMasterDataView() throws IOException {
    server
        .expect(once(), requestTo("http://localhost:8089/*********"))
        .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
        .andRespond(withSuccess(new ClassPathResource("my-mocked-result.json"), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    ResponseEntity<MasterDataViewDTO> response = controller.getMasterDataView();
    assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
    // TODO: Write assertions to see if the DTO matches the JSON structure
}
```

In addition to testing that your actual REST call matches, this also allows you to test if your JSON-to-DTO works as well.

Comment: if i autowire the rest template, will taht be a singleton instance? shared between all the requests

Comment: @ApurvAdarsh Yes, it will be.

Comment: if there are many calls made to the same instance , will it impact the response for the calls it being singleton  @g00glen00b

Comment: no it will not impact the response. Autowiring the resttemplate is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `@RestClientTest` and `MockRestServiceServer`. An example provided in [their documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RestClientTest(RemoteVehicleDetailsService.class)
public class ExampleRestClientTest {

    @Autowired
    private RemoteVehicleDetailsService service;

    @Autowired
    private MockRestServiceServer server;

    @Test
    public void getVehicleDetailsWhenResultIsSuccessShouldReturnDetails()
            throws Exception {
        this.server.expect(requestTo("/greet/details"))
                .andRespond(withSuccess("hello", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        String greeting = this.service.callRestService();
        assertThat(greeting).isEqualTo("hello");
    }

}
```

Comment: i dont want to load the complete context, as i dont want to use the data base

Comment: is there a possibility of doing this using mockito. as we are advised to test using mockito in our project

Comment: @Apurv Adarsh, yes you can. Please refer to the answer by g00glen00b.

Answer (score 0):

1. create bean instead of using `new RestTemplate()` in your services.
2. use Profile("!test") for your bean that use only for non test profile.
3. create test class like this:

   ```
    @SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.profiles.active:test")
    @ActiveProfiles("test")
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @Log4j2
    @Transactional
    public class QabzinoMockTest {


    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
    @Autowired
    private QabzinoLogRepository qabzinoLogRepository;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    private final WebServiceStatus successStatus = new WebServiceStatus();

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private final Gson mapper = new Gson();

    @TestConfiguration
    static class Config {
        @Bean
        public RestTemplate rest() {
            return Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);
        }
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext).build();
        this.restTemplate = (RestTemplate) this.webApplicationContext.getBean("rest");
        LoginOutput responseModel = new LoginOutput();
        responseModel.setStatus("200");
        Mockito.when(
                restTemplate.postForEntity(                            
                        Mockito.eq(LOGIN_URL),
                        Mockito.isA(HttpEntity.class),
                        Mockito.eq(String.class)
                )
        ).thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok().body(mapper.toJson(responseModel)));

    }
   }
   ```

in this sample we create bean with `rest` name in  `static class Config`  and mock it in setup method Before all tests.

4. and preferred test config maybe useful for you `application-test.properties`:

   spring.h2.console.enabled=true

   spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

   spring.jpa.show-sql=true

   spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

   spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

   spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;IGNORECASE=TRUE;

   spring.datasource.username=sa

   spring.datasource.password=sa

and finally when we see restTemplate in our code, mock bean return our responseModel instead of real service call  :)